# The best kind of view/activity for a list that is constantly changed?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking for the best view or activity performance wise that will need to be modified constantly. Imagine some kind of "Conversation" based list, where new elements are added to the conversation all the time.

Would cursors be appropriate here? What about a ListActivity?

Does the choice even matter? Is there any noticable difference in terms of performance? I'm sure that you (by now) understand that I'm new to Android development. I hope you understand.

Comment: Are you experiencing performance issues on any of them?

Comment: No, but since I'm new to the subject (knowing very well that it'll take me a while to even understand how to implement each of them), I would like to know on before-hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the source code of the built-in SMS Android app, and this is the Layout

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        style="?android:attr/listViewWhiteStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="16dip" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/loading_conversations"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So if you are making a "Conversation" app, it is safe to use a `ListView` without performance issues.

Comment: Interesting. Can I somehow use this exact layout in my app? Or will that cause problems in terms of missing resources or what not?

Comment: In this case, you can but you will missing some resources that you probably need to add yourself anyways like ` android:text="@string/loading_conversations"`

Comment: But the "listViewWhiteStyle" reference should work, and will not need to be added?

Comment: I am not sure about that, you can find/look at the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/telephony/SmsMessage.java?av=f) or [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms)

Answer (score 0):

You're really thinking about things backwards here.  Come up with the UI design that effectively shows the information.  Then figure out how to implement that design.  Don't think about individual classes until then.

By the way, you'd only ever use a ListActivity if your main view is pretty much just a ListView.  And you only use cursors if you're making a db request.  You wouldn't think about the type of either-  you're going to be writing your own custom activity for every app (frequently more than one), and you don't choose cursor types at all-  the datasource you're using will pass you one if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. For the most part you can get away with using many different types of views, but assuming you leave it open a long time it will eat up more and more memory if all you ever do is add (vs. remove) to it. This generally means you'll want a strategy to remove some items and reload when applicable (e.g. remove from early on in the "conversation" and add back when you scroll up). I rarely actually use `ListActivity`, but tend to favor just using `ListView`s in regular a `Activity`, but there's nothing wrong with `ListActivity` per se. From what you've described I'd definitely consider some form of `ListView` though. Also look at learning about how adapters work as they're the counterpart to `ListView`s.